# VB: Select every 6th cell in a column and insert to the right

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to start at cell A2 and then select every 6th cell in that column. Next, I want to insert a cell and shift everything to the right.

This is what I have that works so far, but it's long and takes forever to type out:

```
Range("A2,A8,A14,A20,A26,A32,A38,A44,A50,A56,A62,A68,A74").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Please tell me there is a more simple expression to get the desired output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

do it in a loop so you don't have to type it all out.

```
for i = 2 to 10000 step 6
  range("A" & i).Select 
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

next
```

you don't have to do the select, you can also do `range("A"&i).insert Shift:=xlToRight`

Comment: I agree with [not using select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). Also, use the `Cells(i,1)` command instead of concatenating range names. [It is faster and cleaner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073943/range-vs-cells-run-times/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Union` Function to set the range and then move all cells together.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'get last row in column "A"
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

    'set range using Union function
    For i = 2 To lastRow Step 6
        If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Range("A" & i)
        Set rng = Union(Range("A" & i), rng)
    Next

    'move range to right
    rng.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could go like follows:

```
For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    If (cell.Row - 2) Mod 6 = 0 Then cell.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next cell
```

but should your need be not actually shifting cells (i.e. shifting *ALL* row cells at the right of the relevant one) but rather their values only then you could go like follows:

```
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If (cell.Row - 2) Mod 6 = 0 Then cell.Offset(, 1) = cell: cell.ClearContents
    Next cell
```

which is much faster

a few words about what you see in code above:

- the `Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)` part takes care to consider only column "A" cells from "A1" down to its **LAST** non empty one
- the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` part takes care to furtherly filter the former range considering only cells with a "constant" (i.e. not resulting from a formula) value in it

  you could even be more specific like

  - `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)`

    which would consider only "constants" (as above defined) string values
  - `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)`

    which would consider only "constants" (as above defined) numeric values

  the same can be achieved for cell with formulas only just by typing `xlCellTypeFormulas` instead of `xlCellTypeConstants`

Comment: @Krista: did you get through it?

Comment: @Krista: it'd be nice of you to give feedbacks to people trying helping you