# Are these novelty ways [and possibly the best way?] to refer a dynamic cell in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, reference

We usually use the expressions: `Cells(i, 1)`, `Cells(i, "A")`, or `Range("A" & i)` to refer a dynamic cell in VBA, but I find the following *bizarre* code also works:

```
Sub Test1()
For i = 1 To 10000
    Range("A1")(i) = i   
Next
End Sub
```

I also found the *shortcut* notation using the square brackets [ ] for referring to a cell (Yes, I know that a shorthand method of expressing the EVALUATE command) can also be used here like the following codes

```
Sub Test2()
For i = 1 To 10000
    [A1].Resize(1000, 1)(i) = i   
Next
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub Test3()
For i = 1 To 10000
    [A1].Offset(i - 1) = i   
Next
End Sub
```

It's contrary to popular belief that the square brackets can only refer to **fixed** ranges with shortcut notation. I tested all of them and they returned the same outputs.

Honestly, I've never thought those three expressions ever exist, so I guess they're probably new. Is it true?

---

Not only did I find them, I also tested them to see which one is the best. By the best I mean in their performance using timing test. I tested the statements:

1. `Cells(i, 1) = Rnd`
2. `Range("A" & i) = Rnd`
3. `Cells(i, "A") = Rnd`
4. `Range("A1")(i) = Rnd`
5. `[A1].Resize(1000, 1)(i) = Rnd`
6. `[A1].Offset(i - 1) = Rnd`

to the following code

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Long

Randomize
For i = 1 To 1000        'I also tested them with 10,000 loops
    'Put the expression here
Next
End Sub
```

I obtained the time duration to complete on my machine as follow

```
1,000 loops
1               2               3               4               5               6
0.290110725     0.298291317     0.305540433     0.289084126     0.325044276     0.318445433
0.270974218     0.287950980     0.276009685     0.277133638     0.318741694     0.312968414
0.277361318     0.274790389     0.273291810     0.275994401     0.311879789     0.312000675
0.279113453     0.275501647     0.275247422     0.281113426     0.311558662     0.315628943
0.270359637     0.276440868     0.279950951     0.276444561     0.320118775     0.311556754
0.270066136     0.281525061     0.273649022     0.276767648     0.311083246     0.311015128
0.274146235     0.277156933     0.274465750     0.287375210     0.311426416     0.319849274
0.269184843     0.277200430     0.276525859     0.276931561     0.322461782     0.310902381
0.271190611     0.283046575     0.280286123     0.275876294     0.312358236     0.313066500
0.271210909     0.277953463     0.274105173     0.276916590     0.312845710     0.321566549

Average time
0.274371809     0.280985766     0.278907223     0.279363746     0.315751859     0.314700005
```

and

```
10,000 loops
1               2               3               4               5               6
1.897854697     1.975970014     2.026380540     1.963044684     2.667340257     2.404596752
1.893136200     1.958722430     1.997488630     1.957524600     2.412742475     2.364692000
1.915567238     1.991447404     2.026974359     1.972207855     2.396174991     2.408500400
1.885336683     1.964379644     2.001175971     1.950138292     2.362537378     2.369196417
1.889658641     1.959677449     1.998453783     1.984470995     2.372677528     2.366525087
1.885327819     1.963668734     1.997487505     2.038683070     2.367691027     2.380044796
1.878379741     1.958654295     2.002764956     2.008183347     2.368766984     2.362091273
1.894069516     1.960857991     1.994435035     2.031241378     2.377953481     2.367554909
1.894528017     1.972240515     2.003587552     1.961539277     2.364523191     2.373092790
1.883387443     1.965169572     1.999893716     1.948455660     2.363346303     2.368680396


Average time
1.891724600     1.967078805     2.004864205     1.981548916     2.405375362     2.376497482
```

Based on these two results, though the results were inconclusive for comparing the expressions: `Range("A" & i)`, `Cells(i, "A")`, and `Range("A1")(i)` and also for comparing `[A1].Resize(1000, 1)(i)` and `[A1].Offset(i - 1)`, it turned out the fastest performance was `Cells(i, 1)`. Is this true in general? Why so? My guess is during run-time VBA always uses `Cells(i, 1)`, so when the code is being compiled all references in other expressions must be converted to expression 1 since I strongly believe VBA must memorize both its compiled version of the code and whatever expressions we used to write our code. But it's only speculation on my part.

Comment: Nice one. A related test I have done a few month back on a few reference types: [Range VS Cells run times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073943/range-vs-cells-run-times/36073944)

Comment: I'm sorry Mr. @ScottCraner, I don't think it's a dup since the first part is somewhat new. Have you take a look before marking my question as a dup?

Comment: You could post your measurements as an answer to that question, and ask the first part in a separate one.

Comment: @vacip answered your question in his question.  Because the `A1` or `(1,"A")` includes a string that must be parsed into the numeric coordinates it takes longer than simply providing the numeric coordinates directly using Cells.  The rest can be added as an answer to his question, to further prove that Cells is the quickest.

Comment: "It's contrary to popular belief that the square brackets can only refer to fixed ranges" - in your examples [A1] *is* only referring to a fixed range - the offset/resize are then applied to that fixed range to return a different range.

Comment: @ScottCraner The questions to the linked post are "is it really faster? By how much?", meanwhile mine are "I guess they're probably new. Is it true?" and "Is this true in general? Why so?". Clearly, the answer to that question doesn't entirely answer my question. SO it's indeed a completely different question since the subject's already different. Please, use your best judgement before marking my question as a dup. I've never gotten problem like this on Math SE

Comment: It has been reopened, though the answer to your questions have been given in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the following *bizarre* code

Not really. The code is not bizarre.
The thing is, a `Range` variable is a "viewport" for the sheet rather than a fixed box with concrete walls. You absolutely can go beyond the initially defined bounds of your `Range`.

The line

```
Range("A1")(i) = i
```

is equivalent to

```
Range("A1").Cells(i).Value = i
```

which is perfectly doable even though the `Range("A1")` only contains one cell - you are just stepping beyond that cell.

> I've never thought those three expressions ever exist, so I guess they're probably new. Is it true?

No, it's not. They are very old. The oldest Office I have at hand is 2003 and it works there, and I'm pretty confident it used to work in Office 95.

The reason you never heard about them is probably because no one is using them, which is arguably a good thing. While they are valid from the object model's point of view, they are more confusing than more straightforward ways.

> it turned out the fastest performance was `Cells(i, 1)`. Is this true in general? Why so?

I never tested it (and I won't), but logically `Cells(i, 1)` should be the fastest because it does not involve string parsing and/or evaluating. Arguably, all the other options ultimately call `Cells(i, 1)`.