# how to improve excel vba code of many ifs end ifs

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If [C3] > 0 And [B3] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("E-L1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("E-L1").Visible = False
End If
If [C4] > 0 And [B4] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("E-L2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("E-L2").Visible = False
End If
If [C5] > 0 And [B5] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("E-L3").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("E-L3").Visible = False
End If

If [C7] > 0 And [B7] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("M-L1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("M-L1").Visible = False
End If
If [C8] > 0 And [B8] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("M-L2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("M-L2").Visible = False
End If

If [C10] > 0 And [B10] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("MIDPI-1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("MIDPI-1").Visible = False
End If
If [C11] > 0 And [B11] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("MIDPI-2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("MIDPI-2").Visible = False
End If

If [C13] > 0 And [B13] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-1").Visible = False
End If
If [C14] > 0 And [B14] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-2").Visible = False
End If
If [C15] > 0 And [B15] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-3").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-3").Visible = False
End If
If [C16] > 0 And [B16] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-4").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-4").Visible = False
End If

If [C18] > 0 And [B18] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-LR1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-LR1").Visible = False
End If
If [C19] > 0 And [B19] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-LR2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-LR2").Visible = False
End If
If [C20] > 0 And [B20] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-LR3").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-LR3").Visible = False
End If
If [C21] > 0 And [B21] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-LR4").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-LR4").Visible = False
End If

If [C23] > 0 And [B23] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-SR1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-SR1").Visible = False
End If
If [C24] > 0 And [B24] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("BR-SR2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("BR-SR2").Visible = False
End If

If [C26] > 0 And [B26] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("MOD-F1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("MOD-F1").Visible = False
End If
If [C27] > 0 And [B27] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("MOD-F2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("MOD-F2").Visible = False
End If

If [C29] > 0 And [B29] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("MOD-S1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("MOD-S1").Visible = False
End If
If [C30] > 0 And [B30] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("MOD-S2").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("MOD-S2").Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

The above checks for 3 criteria for a worksheet to be visible, if all 3 is not satisfied, then worksheet is hidden

i.e. if the 3 criteria is met, then a certain worksheet will be visible

is there a better way of writing the above code?
seems to be redundant
too many ifs and end ifs

Many thanks

Comment: This question would be better ask on Code Review

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rowsIndex As Variant, sheetNames As Variant

    rowsIndex = Array(3,4,5,7,8,10)
    sheetNames = Array("E-L1","E-L2","E-L3","M-L1","M-L2","MISPI-1")

    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(rowsIndex) To UBound(rowsIndex)
        Sheets(sheetNames(index)).Visible = Cells(rowsIndex(index), 2) > 0 And Cells(rowsIndex(index), 3) > 0 And Cells(1,2) > 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Just fill those two arrays up with all your rows indexes and corresponding sheet names

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you have something like:

```
If [C3] > 0 And [B3] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("E-L1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("E-L1").Visible = False
End If
```

You can shorten it.  Since this :

```
( [C3] > 0 And [B3] > 0 And [B1] > 0 )
```

...returns `True` or `False` (without an `If`).  ...and if it's `True` you want `Visible=True`. Therefore:

```
Sheets("E-L1").Visible  =  ( [C3] > 0 And [B3] > 0 And [B1] > 0 )
```

...is the equivalent.  That will make a big change in all the similar sections.

---

Something that used to seem like a waste of time to me but actually is an important habit is **proper spacing and indenting** (especially when sharing your code with others of forums!).

There are various Simple example loose rules at ultimately the "style" is up to you, just make sure it's organized whatever it is.

For example, this:

```
Sub myExample
If [C29] > 0 And [B29] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
Sheets("MOD-S1").Visible = True
Else
Sheets("MOD-S1").Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Should be:

```
Sub myExample
    If [C29] > 0 And [B29] > 0 And [B1] > 0 Then
        Sheets("MOD-S1").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("MOD-S1").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

---

One more thing, **do not** get in the habit of using shorthand like [A1]+[B2].  That form of cell references is full of potential issues, and is mean for us in the immediate window for debugging, not as part of your code.

There are a few "proper" ways you can do it , the most common being, ***instead of***:

```
[A1]
```

(declare at least one worksheet at the beginning of the procedure)

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("mySheetName")
```

...and then you refer to the cell like:

```
ws.Ramge("A1")
```

It may seem like a lot more typing but there are important reasons for it. Proper organization will save you (and those you show your code to!) from headaches in the long run.

---

If you'd like to make that change and update the code in your question, we can take another look.

Comment: I personally use [SomeNamedRange] all the time instead of Range("SomeCellAddress").  It strikes me that Range("SomeCellAddress") is a far worse sin than [SomeNamedRange] given you have just hard-coded in something that then needs to be changed if someone later wants to insert rows/columns above/left of SomeCellAddress.

Comment: The majority would disagree with you.  I've seen people practically yelled at on here for posting questions with shortcut references.  (There are reasons it's called "[shortcut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-cells-by-using-shortcut-notation)" and why everyone doesn't use it.  We don't "just like typing more".)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770437/are-these-novelty-ways-and-possibly-the-best-way-to-refer-a-dynamic-cell-in-v

Comment: That link doesn't give you a compelling case not to use the shortcut reference. It just points out that it's *slightly* faster to use a full reference, and it uses a very contrived example of referencing cells from VBA thousands and tens of thousands of times to find that slight difference. But if you're doing that, then you've got a much bigger problem than Range("A1") vs [A1].

Comment: On the other hand, using Range("C10") or [C10] are both equally bad compared to Range("SomeNamedRangePointingAtC10") or [SomeNamedRangePointingAtC10] because you've just hard coded a reference into your app that will point at the wrong place if someone adds/deletes rows/columns to the left/above that cell. *That's* a yelling offence.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation to DisplayName's code which I think is pretty good.
Range B1 was common to all conditions, so why not place that as your first condition, and remove it from the rest of your code. Your ranges came in pairs so add them to an array. I placed all of the first half of the pair in the first half of the array so that you can make use of /2 as a Mod value to get the second half of the array values. The sheets array should of course equal your /2 value

```
Sub sheetVisibility()
On Error GoTo NoSheet
Dim ranges As Variant, sheets As Variant, arrayLen As Integer
If ([B1] > 0) Then
    ranges = Array("C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", _
                   "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6")
    arrayLen = UBound(ranges) / 2
    sheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheetx")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ranges) Mod arrayLen 
        sheets(sheets(i)).Visible = (Range(ranges(i)) > 0 And Range(ranges(i + arrayLen)) > 0)
    Next i
End If
End
NoSheet:
End Sub
```