# Using data type "range" similar to "collection" - VBA

Tags: vba

I have an issue I was wondering if anyone could assist me with... I would like to use data type "range" in a similar way to how "collection" works. I would like to use a counter and a loop: "rng(i) = value" where i can be 1, 7, 100 etc. Hence, if I add "A1, A5, C3, D6" to rng, I would like "rng(3)= 3" to set cell C3 equal to 3. Using the "for each x in range" is not an option with regard to how the code are supposed to work. It it possible to make that work?

An alternative solution for me would be if I could add all individual cells in 7 different collections to one variable of data type range.

Any suggestions?

Regards, 
Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that would only work if your collection contained a single continuous range.

With a collection of disconnected cells, each cell is its own [`Area`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas), and trying to directly index the combined `Range` will give you unexpected results: the index will be applied to the *first* area, and because it's a single cell area, it will [go out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38794050/11683), so e.g. for the range of `A1, A5, C3, D6`, `rng(3)` will refer to cell A3 (third cell down relative to A1).

To make indexing work the way you want, you need to mention the `Areas` property explicitly:

```
Dim coll As Range

' Set initial contents - has to be at least one cell, can be more
Set coll = some_worksheet.Range("A1,A5,C3")  

' This is how you add to already stored "collection"
Set coll = Application.Union(coll, some_worksheet.Range("D6"))

coll.Areas(3) = 42  ' Sets C3 to 42
```

Comment: This is great, I'll give this a go tomorrow morning. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works with any ranges, contiguous or otherwise

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1,B5,E7:E9")

    Dim v As Variant, a As Range, r As Range

    ReDim v(1 To 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas
        For Each r In a
            v(UBound(v)) = r.Value
            ReDim Preserve v(1 To UBound(v) + 1)
        Next
    Next
    ReDim Preserve v(1 To UBound(v) - 1)

    Debug.Print v(1)
    Debug.Print v(2)
    Debug.Print v(3)

End Sub
```

Comment: Fortunately for my case, I work with individual cells and not a continuous range. But I'll try this out! Next time it may be just what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

> [MSDN: Looping Through a Range of
>   Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/looping-through-a-range-of-cells)
>
> Another easy way to loop through a range is to use a **For Each...Next
>   loop** with the collection of cells specified in the **Range property**.
>   Visual Basic automatically sets an object variable for the next cell
>   each time the loop runs. The following procedure loops through the
>   range A1:D10, setting to 0 (zero) any number whose absolute value is
>   less than 0.01.
>
> ```
> Sub RoundToZero2() 
>  For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells 
>  If Abs(c.Value) < 0.01 Then c.Value = 0 
>  Next 
> End Sub
> ```