# Cells property - Run-time error 91

Tags: excel, vba, range, runtime-error, cells

So, I am trying to create sub procedure, where one of the arguments is column name.

Column name is then converted to column number.

```
Dim ColNum As Integer: ColNum = Range(ColumnNM & 1).Column
```

But when I try to use column number in range, with cell property I get 91 run-time error. Most of the solutions here are for not properly setting the range.

> Run-time error 91

This here gives me that error :

```
Dim rngTA As Range: Set rngTA = wsTA.Range(Cells(24, ColNum))
```

and this (experimented, not sure if this is proper way to set range with string address)

```
Dim addr As String: addr = Cells(24, ColNum).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
Dim rngTA As Range: Set rngTA = wsTA.Range(addr)
```

I am stuck there.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Set rngTA = wsTA.Range(wsTA.Cells(24, ColNum),wsTA.Cells(24, ColNum))`

Comment: @Shai Rado Same 91 error

Comment: @Shai RadoI don't know what is going on, when I create new sub, with only essentials your line is working,but in original code debugger stopped on setting rngTA range, I have to recheck whole code. Sorry, and thanks.

Comment: No problem , you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `Range`.  `Cells()` is a range object:

```
Dim rngTA As Range: Set rngTA = wsTA.Cells(24, ColNum)
```

When using range objects in a `Range` it needs to have two a beginning an an end.  Since you only want one, just refer to that directly.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a module, you can just use match, nevertheless, here is a function:

```
Function Letter(oSheet As Worksheet, name As String, Optional num As Integer)
If num = 0 Then num = 1
Letter = Application.Match(name, oSheet.Rows(num), 0)
'Letter = Split(Cells(, Letter).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Name here is the name of your column header, oSheet is the name of the sheet, there is an optional variable that can be used as a number if the row you are searching is not 1. If you remove the quotation you can get the letter, rather than the number.

Comment: This is the slowest method to get the job done.  Excel works with numbers and has to parse any string to a numerical coordinates.  By changing the column to a string, Excel then needs to parse it back to a number.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073943/range-vs-cells-run-times