# How to set copy range for i rows and set number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

Right now my vba code has this snippet for copying  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy`. I have i properly set up so that it will copy the rows I want. However, it is currently copying the entirety of all the specified rows. How can I have it continue to count rows but also only copy from say column A to Q? **So a range of i rows from column A to Q**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,1),Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,17)).Copy
```

Or

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i & ":Q" & i).Copy
```

Or

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Resize(,17).Copy
```

Depending on the size of the loop the first will be the quickest(See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073943/range-vs-cells-run-times)).  It can also be shortened with a `With` block:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     .Range(.Cells(i,1),.Cells(i,17)).Copy
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: @Forkinator9000 please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.