# ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)).Select does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I only have a single workbook with one sheet open with only a number in cell(2,3).

when the code reaches this line:

```
Debug.Print Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)).Value
```

or this line:

```
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)).Select
```

I get

> Method of "range' of object'_gobal" failed

Since this line is essentially copied from "How to select cells/ranges by using Visual Basic procedures in Excel" in Microsoft Docs, I am perplexed as to why it doesn't work.

```
Sub testCode()
 Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3)).Value
 ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3)).Select
 End Sub
```

Comment: Range wants two cells to create a range, just use `ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3).Value` and `ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3).Select`

Comment: BTW: Microsoft docs aren't always the greatest... see for example [How to avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @NareshBhople yes it can take a string as a single cell.  For example `Range("A1")` but when using actual range object it must be two, a start and a finish.  As to your example the `Address` returns a string.  But I would not recommend doing that as it is the long slow way around.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073943/range-vs-cells-run-times

Comment: @ScottCraner I got your point. You are referring cells as range object (Start and end) in your comment. Yes, I agree with you .. Thanks for response

Comment: Thanks Scott. Using two cells (and only two, three also causes an error)  solves the problem.