# How can I speed up this For Each loop in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, foreach

I have an Worksheet_Change macro that hides/unhides rows depending on the choice a user makes in a cell with a data validation list.

The code takes a minute to run. It's looping over c.2000 rows. I'd like it to take closer to a few seconds so it becomes a useful user tool.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Exit the routine early if there is an error
    On Error GoTo EExit

    'Manage Events
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Declare Variables
    Dim rng_DropDown As Range
    Dim rng_HideFormula As Range
    Dim rng_Item As Range

    'The reference the row hide macro will look for to know to hide the row
    Const str_HideRef As String = "Hide"

    'Define Variables
    'The range that contains the week selector drop down
    Set rng_DropDown = Range("rng_WeekSelector")
    'The column that contains the formula which indicates if a row should 
    'be hidden c.2000 rows
    Set rng_HideFormula = Range("rng_HideFormula")

    'Working Code
    'Exit sub early if the Month Selector was not changed
    If Not Target.Address = rng_DropDown.Address Then GoTo EExit

    'Otherwise unprotect the worksheet
    wks_DailyPlanning.Unprotect (str_Password)

    'For each cell in the hide formula column
    For Each rng_Item In rng_HideFormula

        With rng_Item
            'If the cell says "hide"
            If .Value2 = str_HideRef Then

                'Hide the row
                .EntireRow.Hidden = True

            Else
                'Otherwise show the row
                .EntireRow.Hidden = False

            End If
        End With
    'Cycle through each cell
    Next rng_Item

    EExit:
    'Reprotect the sheet if the sheet is unprotected
    If wks_DailyPlanning.ProtectContents = False Then wks_DailyPlanning.Protect (str_Password)


    'Clear Events
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I have looked at some links provided by other users on this website and I think the trouble lies in the fact I'm having to iterate through each row individually.

Is it possible to create something like an array of .visible settings I can apply to the entire range at once?

Comment: You may benefit from [Understanding Read/ Write Speeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53987345/speed-up-excel-vba-copying-data-from-one-sheet-to-another) from hard disk vs memory.

Comment: if you have the result of your visible calculations in a (hidden) column on the row, then apply a `.autofilter` to all the false values in one go. It would be much faster than looping over all of them.

Comment: I like the idea of an `AutoFilter`, or else go loop through an array and use `Union` to create two range object to hide/unhide all at once. That would be faster than to iterate over items and hide/unhide rows one by one. Futhermore, working code might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead =)

Comment: Also if you need the rows hidden instead of filtered (there is a small difference) then this can be done with an `.advancedfilter`. [Shameless self plug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232543/advanced-filter-in-vba-excel-with-combobox/58233316#58233316)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
Dim mergedRng As Range

'.......

rng_HideFormula.EntireRow.Hidden = False
For Each rng_Item In rng_HideFormula
    If rng_Item.Value2 = str_HideRef Then
        If Not mergedRng Is Nothing Then
            Set mergedRng = Application.Union(mergedRng, rng_Item)
        Else
            Set mergedRng = rng_Item
        End If
    End If
Next rng_Item
If Not mergedRng Is Nothing Then mergedRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Set mergedRng = Nothing

'........
```

Comment: This was the fastest solution for me. Thank you!

Comment: @jakrooster. Try it on 50,000 rows to see its real power. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest copying your data range to a memory-based array and checking that, then using that data to adjust the visibility of each row. It minimizes the number of interactions you have with the worksheet `Range` object, which takes up lots of time and is a big performance hit for large ranges.

```
Sub HideHiddenRows()
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim data As Variant
    Set dataRange = Sheet1.Range("A13:A2019")
    data = dataRange.Value

    Dim rowOffset As Long
    rowOffset = IIf(LBound(data, 1) = 0, 1, 0)

    ApplicationPerformance Flag:=False

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        If data(i, 1) = "Hide" Then
            dataRange.Rows(i + rowOffset).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            dataRange.Rows(i + rowOffset).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next i
    ApplicationPerformance Flag:=True
End Sub

Public Sub ApplicationPerformance(ByVal Flag As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Flag
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Flag
    Application.EnableEvents = Flag
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

to increase perfomance you can populate dictionary with range addresses, and hide or unhide at once, instead of hide/unhide each particular row (but this is just in theory, you should test it by yourself), just an example:

```
Sub HideHiddenRows()
    Dim cl As Range, x As Long
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cl In Range("A1", Cells(x, "A"))
        If cl.Value = 0 Then dic.Add cl.Address(0, 0), Nothing
    Next cl

    Range(Join(dic.keys, ",")).EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

demo:

[image]