# Advanced search using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, database, vba, search, listbox

I have a list of data (20,000+ products) there is different pricing depending on a condition of the product, users need the ability to look up product pricing at certain grades quickly, my current challenge is using vlookup's fail as often the users will just keyword search and not have the exact description. I want to leave in the existing lookup using vlookup as that will remain a quick search when the user has the exact product title but want to add an advanced search in when they only have a keyword (I have tried data validation searchable lists but they are slow and unreliable)

I have created a Listbox but can't get the code to search my data set and then display the results,

this is the code I'm using (Stock data has all my products and pricing) and my 2nd sheet is called Search where I want users to find what they are looking for

```
enter code here

Private Sub cmdsearch_click()

Dim Rownum As Long
Dim Searchrow As Long

Rownum = 2
Searchrow = 2

Worksheets("Stock Data").Activate

Do Until Cells(Rownum, 1).Value = ""
If InStr(1, Cells(Rownum, 1).Value, txtkeywords.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Searchrow, 1).Value = Cells(rownnum, 1).Value
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Searchrow, 2).Value = Cells(rownnum, 2).Value
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Searchrow, 3).Value = Cells(rownnum, 3).Value
   Searchrow = Searchrow + 1
End If
Rownum = Rownum + 1



Loop

If Searchrow = 2 Then
MsgBox "Sorry No products found, please request a price"
End If

Lstsearchresults.RowSource = "SearchResults"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but the link is in German and I am more than a little rusty at VBA

Comment: What about `VLOOKUP` with wild cards?

Comment: Oh, and with regard to `Range.Find`, Microsoft does have online documentation in multiple languages.

Comment: @ronrosenfeld I am struggling to understand how I would wrap the Range.find into my code thats why I looked at search

Comment: Another possibility is to [read in your list to a memory based array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58304857/11936678) for performance. It can speed cell loops costing seconds to near instant.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link, here is the correct one: [Range.Find - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find). It also contains a simple example to illustrate how to loop through all results with the `.Find` method.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments, you could use `Range.Find` like this:

```
Private Sub cmdsearch_click()

Dim rowResult As Long
Dim strSearch As String

rowResult = 2
strSearch = txtkeywords.Value

Dim rowLast As Long
rowLast = Worksheets("Stock Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rngFound As Range
Dim firstAdress As String

With Worksheets("Stock Data").Range("A1:A" & rowLast)
    Set rngFound = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

        firstAddress = rngFound.Address
        Do
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowResult , 1).Value2 = rngFound.Value2
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowResult , 2).Value2 = rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value2
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowResult , 3).Value2 = rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value2
            rowResult = rowResult + 1

            Set rngFound = .FindNext
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> firstAdress

    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry No products found, please request a price"
    End If
End With

Lstsearchresults.RowSource = "SearchResults"

End Sub
```

An even faster approach would be to store everything in an array and looping through that. When starting out however I found it easier to work with less abstract methods and learning step by step.